# how to get individual element from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have dateValues as follows,

```
[dateVals] = 031012,041012;
```

it is comma seperated values. I want to make this as array and to get individual values . As i am new to PHP , i want some one's help .

```
$val = array[dataVals];
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($val);$i++) {
  echo "val is".$val[$i]."\n";
}
```

is not working

Comment: $newarray = explode(",", $val);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dateVals = '031012,041012';

$dateValsArr = explode(',', $dateVals);
   foreach( $dateValsArr as $date) {
}
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$dateVals = '031012,041012';
$pieces = explode(",", $dateVals);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($pieces);$i++) {
  echo "val is".$pieces[$i]."\n";
}
```

it will give you proper output.

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/PQBiZ3

Answer (score 0):

**Try this One**

```
$dateVals = '031012,041012';

$date_arr[] = explode(',',$dateVals);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($date_arr) ; $i++)
    {
        print $date_arr[$i].'<br />';
    }
```